# Extra Add to Cart Button for simple Product

Tags: magento-1.9, product, addtocart

I have a website, sell a products with and without installation service. I want **two add to cart buttons**, one with and one without installation on a product page. The price for installation is variable for each product.

I write the code below in {theme}/template/ajaxcart/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml near Add to Cart button. The price that is displayed add the button is € 0,00 it should be € 350,00 and when you use this button the totaal page refresh.

```
<?php 
if($_product->getSampleProductId()): 
    $_price = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')->getAttributeRawValue($_product->getSampleProductId(), 'price', Mage::app()->getStore()); 
    $_formattedPrice = Mage::helper('core')->currency($_price, true, false);
    $_buttonTitle = "Order Sample @".$_formattedPrice;?>
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $_buttonTitle ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo Mage::getUrl('checkout/cart/add/product/'.$_product->getSampleProductId()) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $_buttonTitle ?></span></span></button><?php endif; ?>
```

How can I make this extra add to cart button to work? Thanks

Comment: have you created new attribute to store installation price?

Comment: I don't use a atrribute for the price now

Comment: then how will you get the installation price for particular product ?

Comment: That's one problem I don't know. Can you tell me how?

Comment: if you dont want to do it via custom option then you can create new attribute called `installation_price`  to store installation price

Comment: HOw do I get this to work in the code?

Comment: You don't have to make extra cart button for this. Just use default custom option simple product for installation service.
You have to create a simple product with regular price.
Add custom option in that product for Installation service and put extra price of installation only.
It will give you extra check-box of installation service and its price in that product. When user selects that check-box then price will update automatically. CAN YOU PLEASE EXPLAIN TO ME HOW I WOULD DO THIS, IN DETAIL? STEP BY STEP? PLEASE?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to make extra cart button for this. Just use default custom option simple product for installation service.

1. You have to create a simple product with regular price.
2. Add custom option in that product for Installation service and put extra price of installation only.

It will give you extra check-box of installation service and its price in that product. When user selects that check-box then price will update automatically.

Comment: I want a extra add to cart button for this option. At the production site this is in use now. But we want a extra add to cart button for the installation service. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: A custom option with its own add to cart button is also a good start